# Using parallel-level in azcopy when transferring data from an Azure VM to an AWS VM

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

How does one precisely utilize `--parallel-level` when using azcopy on Ubuntu 14.04 to speed up download performance?

I chose a value of `100`, but without any reason (just to see what happens). I can't find related documentation online.

I'm using it to transfer files from an Azure blob to an AWS EC2 VM. It's just a t2.micro instance - however I'm using it for testing purposes and once I get the hang of azcopy, I'm open to using a bigger instance. I have to transfer ~50 GB of data, mostly low res image (i.e. lots of files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

> Option `--parallel-level` specifies the number of concurrent copy
>   operations. By default, AzCopy starts a certain number of concurrent
>   operations to increase the data transfer throughput. The number of
>   concurrent operations is equal eight times the number of processors
>   you have. If you are running AzCopy across a low-bandwidth network,
>   you can specify a lower number for `--parallel-level` to avoid failure
>   caused by resource competition.

Under most of the cases you don't need to specify this option, only when you're running AzCopy across a low-bandwidth network, you can specify a lower number of this option.